# Listing VirtIO devices from a shell in a linux guest

Tags: virtio

As the title already summarizes, is there a way (a tool or a simple command) to list available (thus recognized by a linux guest) VirtIO devices ?

Comment: If the guest uses a (virtual) PCI bus, `lspci` should be the simplest solution.

Comment: @berndbausch very good suggestion, thanks. Unfortunately the guest uses MMIO (memory map) transport.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @berndbausch the `lspci` lists virtio devices when the guest uses a (virtual) PCI bus.

Also as answered in a similar [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1603529/how-to-find-all-virtio-disks-on-machine) question, `lsblk` can help for block devices.

Finally, it should be noted that virtio kernel drivers seem to export a lot of information to sysfs. So searching /sys for driver/virtio*/features should help identify virtio devices used by the kernel.